# Using ajax to process a request from a generated list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of records from a database structured via a PHP loop.
Problem is, I need a way to delete records (Without refreshing the page would be the best) but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

So far I've got a span (Using bootstrap, so its a glyphicon icon (an X)) - the user should click this to delete a specific record. The problem is that when this button is clicked it sends all of the unique ID's of the current table to the ajax script, which, obviously is not good.

Here is what I have:
Generated records:

```
while($row = $ret2->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th>#</th>';
                echo '<th>'.$row['type'].'</th>';
                echo '<th>'.$row['func'].'</th>';
                echo '<th>'.$row['trg'].'</th>';
                echo '<th>
                <span id="deleteRecordSpan" style="cursor:pointer" class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove">'.$row['uniqueID'].'</span>
                </th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $loop++;
        }
```

to ajax script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.remove').click(function() {
                var input = $('.remove').text();
                $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: {
                        uniqueid: input,
                    },
                    type: 'POST', // GET or POST from the form
                    url: './ajax/deleteRecord.php', // the file to call from the form
                    success: function(response) { // on success..
                       show10();
                       allToday();
                   }
               });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

The span's content has ONLY the UniqueID it is associated with inside of it.

I am struggling to find a way to send ONLY the specific UniqueID that was clicked to the ajax script for deletion.

Here is what's happening:

```
UniqueID | Type     | Func | otherID |
500      | Computer | Full | 123     | X
557      | Computer | Full | 125     | X
654      | Computer | Full | 12564   | X
```

If any of the X's in the table above are clicked, it would send `500557654` to the ajax script, when I need it to ONLY send the ID that the X is associated with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the selector `$('.remove')` jQuery will select EVERY element with the class `remove`, in your case all the `remove` spans.

Change `input = $('.remove').text()` to `input = $(this).text()`.

In addition, you can assign a property to the `span` and get the ID from it:

In your PHP:

```
<span id="deleteRecordSpan" data-uid="'.$row['uniqueID'].'" style="cursor:pointer" class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove">'.$row['uniqueID'].'</span>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
var input = $(this).data('uid');
```

so you don't need to be working with plain text.